# How to put block level content above particles-js

Tags: html, css, particles.js

I'm trying to use [particles.js](https://vincentgarreau.com/particles.js/) as a background on my webpage. All the examples I've seen have the particles as the background of the entire webpage (with no scrolling on the page). However, I only want the particles as the background of my page header (using bootstrap 4):

```css
#particles-js {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="particles-js"></div>

<!-- section 1: should have particles as background -->
<div class="py-5 text-center text-light bg-primary">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 text-center my-5">
        <h1>header content...</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- section 2: should not have particles as background -->
<div class="py-5 text-center text-light bg-secondary">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 text-center my-5">
        <h1>other content...</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Right now the particles are above both sections but behind all text, buttons, images, etc.. How do I get the particles to go completely behind section 2? I've tried setting the z-index of section 2 to 9999 but the particles were still visible in that section.

This may not be the best way to do it but none of the other methods I've tried have worked either. Setting section 1 and particles-js height to a percentage works well on a large screen, but when the height of the screen is small the text in the text in section 1 hovers over into section 2. Same issue happens on certain devices when setting the heights to an exact pixel value. Putting content directly inside the particles-js div hasn't work well either.

Any solution to get the particles behind section 2 without compromising responsiveness would be great.

Answer (score 1):

download [particle.js](https://github.com/VincentGarreau/particles.js/) file form github..go to the link

```
<div id="particles-js">
 <div class="py-5 text-center text-light bg-primary">
   <div class="container">
     <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-12 text-center my-5">
         <h1>header content...</h1>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

add this lines

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="particles.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
```

into the body after your html code....
Inside downloaded particle.js file there was a folder named [demo -> js -> app.js] copy that file and particle.js file put it your file location open app.js file

```
particlesJS('orange',

  {
    "particles": {
      "number": {
        "value": 200,
        "density": {
          "enable": true,
          "value_area": 800
        }
      },
```

above orange section enter your own id --- particle-js ---- any problem comment me

Comment: Didn't work when I tried it. See my edit for a link to a demo that you can mess around with.

Comment: Detailed me where you getting your problem---- if its solved accept the answer it helps other particle.js related question

Answer (score 0):

If you have a fixed header, lets say 100px you can use the following CSS

```
body *{
   Position: absolute;
   z-index:1
}

#particles-js {
   position: absolute;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100px;
   z-index: 0 !important
}
```

This will push all elements on your website forward 1 layer with exception to the body, whilst particles-js is set back to layer position 0, thus setting it as a background.

Comment: This didn't work when I tried it. I added a link to a demo of the issue I'm having if you want to mess around and see if you can get it to work.

Comment: I notices i didnt put position absolute on the body css code did you do it with a position absolute?